# How do I create nodes to view onto the 3D scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[This is what I'm looking for!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amArR.png)

This may be a stupid question but how do I create a node to view on the scene view of my cube so I can visually see what is walkable and what isn't?

I'm using Unity 2019.1.9

I have tried using an Node Editor, to no avail. I have also tried to use a shader graph, but nothing seems to work.

I don't want  a tile based node system as my game isn't tile based. I want each node on certain cubes so I can visually see what is walkable and what isn't. Please help me.

Comment: I have been told I can use handles to create visual nodes on my scene view cubes. Just wondering if that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the pink spheres you see in the images are made using the [Gizmos](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html) class.

```
private bool isWalkable;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Color gizmosColor = Gizmos.color;
        Gizmos.color = isWalkable ? Color.green : Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position + Vector3.up, 1);
        Gizmos.color = gizmosColor ;
    }
#endif
```